# Visual Studio 2010 Unit Test

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, white-box-testing

I want to test a couple of functions in my source code with unit tests. Now If I run my test I don't get any test results.

Here is a simple Code Snippet what I try to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class UnitTestBlueSmart

        int main(){
        public:
        [TestMethod()]
        hello();
        }
}

void hello(){
 cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not performing the unit tests correctly.
You should rely on not getting [Asserts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx), not on printing to the console.

The concept is to check methods and make sure they return the correct value.

See the following links for more details:

http://whinery.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/native-c-unit-testing-with-ms-test/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Specifically using your code, an example of a correct unit test would be:

```
string hello()
{
 return "Hello World!";
}
```

and creating a TestMethod which will Assert if the value is incorrect.
For instance:

```
[TestMethod]
void HelloTest()
{
    string expected = "Hello World";
    string result = hello();
    Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::Assert::AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: Can u please modify my HelloWorld Snippet to the rigtht way. So I can see the function in the context.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example, the first link in my answer really sums it up though.

Comment: thanks a lot now I will try it. If it doesn't work I will upload my code again.